# How to subtract two numbers in assembly language

Tags: assembly

```
.model small      

.data               ;data section
  message db  " Enter a number $"
  message2 db " Enter another number $"
  message3 db "  + $"
  message4 db "  = $"
.code
    main proc

       mov ax, seg message  ;3shan minf3sh nn2l el seg msg direct
       mov ds, ax           ;el ds first part mn l string
       mov dx, offset message   ;
       mov ah, 9h
       int 21h      ;3shan y-do it , le print l strings on the screen

       mov ah, 1h  ;read character wl input stored in al
       int 21h                                            

       mov bl, al


       mov ah, 0Eh       ;print new line sequence
       mov al, 0Dh
       int 10h
       mov al, 0Ah
       int 10h

       mov ax, seg message2     ;print msg 2
       mov ds, ax
       mov dx, offset message2
       mov ah,9h
       int 21h 

       mov ah, 1h
       int 21h  

       mov cl, al   

       mov ah, 0Eh       ;print new line sequence
       mov al, 0Dh
       int 10h
       mov al, 0Ah
       int 10h

       mov dl, bl
       mov ah, 2h  
       int 21h 


       mov ax, seg message3
       mov ds, ax
       mov dx, offset message3
       mov ah,9h
       int 21h 

       mov dl, cl
       mov ah, 2h 
       int 21h 

       mov ax, seg message4
       mov ds, ax
       mov dx, offset message4
       mov ah,9h
       int 21h

       sub bl, 30h       ;3shan byd5al l 7aga int fa 3yzen n7wlo le
       sub cl, 30h       ;decimal b3den nrg3o int tani


       sub bl, cl       

       add bl, 30h      ;rg3nah int xD

       mov dl, bl      ;bl 3shan hya ely fiha el sum
       mov ah, 2h
       int 21h
    endp        ;end main


end main        ;end the program
```

This is a code to subtract 2 numbers from the user. I'm trying to add the Multiplication and create a loop for it but I fail everytime, what should I do? I'm self-studying this language.

Comment: I don't even see a `mul` or `imul` instruction, let alone any description of exactly how it fails.  This is not a **minimal** or complete example of the problem you're having.

Answer (score 2):

Your program looks fine except that it has an anomaly. Your *message3* will display a **plus** sign where the program actually performs a subtraction! Not very logical, don't you agree?

---

To quickly change this program so it performs multiplication change the `sub bl, cl` into the following:

```
mov al, bl  ;BL is 1st number
mul cl      ;Multiply with 2nd number, product is in AX
mov bl, al  ;Only use the low byte in AL
```

Do note that the product must yield a 1-digit result in this very basic program!

- Valid choices include: 0 x 7, 3 x 2, 9 x 1, ...
- Invalid choices include: 5 x 4, 2 x 7, 8 x 9, ...